# Accessing default resources from outside rules

Tags: snakemake

Is it possible to access Snakemake (default) resources, specifically `tmpdir`, early in a Snakefile? The purpose is to do the following (with `resources.tmpdir` as a placeholder):

```
all:
    expand("{dir}/{sample}.bam", dir=resources.tmpdir, sample=samples)
```

I realize that resources at that point in time can/will be overriden by resource definitions in rules.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the dictionary `snakemake.DefaultResources.defaults`. Printed at the start of a snakefile it shows on my system:

```
{'mem_mb': 'max(2*input.size_mb, 1000)', 'disk_mb': 'max(2*input.size_mb, 1000)', 'tmpdir': 'system_tmpdir'
```

I don't know if this is the recommended way or a hack. I found it by opening an interactive python terminal, issue `import snakemake`, noted the existence of a promising `snakemake.DefaultResources` object and from there the promising `snakemake.DefaultResources.defaults`.

Comment: Thanks, good find! The dictionary is `snakemake.DefaultResources.defaults` (terminating `s`), but unfortunately it only contains the default resources that Snakemake itself sets, it does not get updated with resources set via profile at runtime.

I realized though that the `all` rule is a rule like any other, so I should be able to access resources as usual (e.g. the example I gave should work). It doesn't in my case since I pass a list of output files to `all`, and during list creation I cannot access the normal rule `resources` object. I may have to change to flow to make this possible.